# Update table column depending on other table in sql->oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what I have so far

```
BEGIN
             UPDATE t1
                set t1.LANGUAGE_ID = (case NETWORK.NID
                        when 11 then 10
                        else 7
                        end)
                FROM PROFILE, NETWORK where
                PROFILE.STATUS in ('A','U','S','H','I')
                AND PROFILE.MID = t1.MID
                AND NETWORK.MID = t1.MID
                AND t1.IS_DELETED = 'N'
END;
```

Getting error:

```
"ORA-06550: line 7, column 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 2, column 18:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 12, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted"
```

I want to update t1 when t1.is_deleted='N', and same mid in profile has status AUSHI. All tables have a column mid.  Any ideas why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement does not have a `FROM` clause in Oracle.

It sounds like you want a correlated update

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.language_id = (SELECT (CASE WHEN network.nid = 11 
                                      THEN 10
                                      ELSE 7
                                  END)
                           FROM profile,
                                network
                          WHERE profile.status IN ('A','U','S','H','I')
                            AND profile.mid = t1.mid
                            AND network.mid = t1.mid
                            AND t1.is_deleted = 'N');
```

This will update every row of `t1` setting `language_id` to `NULL` if the correlated subquery returns no rows.  If you only want to update rows in `t1` where there is a matching row returned by the subquery

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.language_id = (SELECT (CASE WHEN network.nid = 11 
                                      THEN 10
                                      ELSE 7
                                  END)
                           FROM profile,
                                network
                          WHERE profile.status IN ('A','U','S','H','I')
                            AND profile.mid = t1.mid
                            AND network.mid = t1.mid
                            AND t1.is_deleted = 'N')
  WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                  FROM profile,
                       network
                 WHERE profile.status IN ('A','U','S','H','I')
                   AND profile.mid = t1.mid
                   AND network.mid = t1.mid
                   AND t1.is_deleted = 'N');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.   though now i'm getting ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @Justin works great, but if your table is large then consider using MERGE instead. With the provided query, you are running the nested SELECT query once for each row of table `t1`.

I found this link very useful: [8 Bulk Update Methods Compared](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450)